# macOS Enrolment - Devices only being added as placeholders

Tags: server.app, profile-manager

We have an office of about 15 Mac computers, and I'm looking to setup a Mac Mini server, to centralise the management of these devices. I've setup the Mac Mini server with the Server app and enabled both the *Open Directory* and *Profile Manager* roles.

I've enabled the option to *sign configuration profiles* and selected the *Signing Certificate* certificate.

In the profile manager, I've created an enrollment profile and unticked the *restrict use to devices with placeholders* option.

On the computer that I want to join, I've first installed the *trust profile* and then I've run the enrollment profile to join the computer.

The computer shows up under the *usage* as having joined the profile, and under devices, it's successfully adding the device (including the Serial Number and Computer Name), but it's only adding it as a placeholder.

I can't seem to find anyone who is in a similar situation than me, but I should add the following:

- We use a managed service, and don't have access to our firewall rules, so I'm not sure if we need to make any exceptions
- Nothing is showing up under activity (active or completed tasks)
- Our financials are handled by our parent company, so there is no way for me to get a DUNS number, so therefore no way for me to enroll in the device enrollment program.

Is there anything I can do to centralise the management of my computers without having a DUNS number and/or making firewall changes?